# Is a question on QA-related techwriting on-topic for this site?

Tags: discussion

There's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720690/test-architecture-design-document) by other user on SO. I tried to clarify the subject and it appears that it's between QA architecture and QA-related technical writing.

I'm almost sure that it is off-topic on SO. But I'm confused with proposing a better suitable site. Most probably this is SQA. I've read the help topics, but still not sure.

Please approve if the question is on-topic for SQA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see why it would not be a good fit for this site.

Honestly, I believe that the site would be more worthwhile if there was more questions of this type asked here. Questions that are more geared to QA in general, principles, practices and such.